# Binding a list to a flow of WrapPanels

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, scrollview, itemscontrol

I am trying to do an interface in WPF where a list of item is displayed, taking as little vertical space as possible:

[image: mockup]

My instinct was to use an ItemsControl to bind my list, and to put the UI for each item into a WrapPanel. Unfortunately by default, each item starts at a new line regardless of the window's size. Adding a StackPanel with `Orientation="Horizontal"` makes all items in a single line, regardless of the size...

```
    <!--<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">-->
        <ItemsControl  Margin="0,4" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Watchers}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Core:Watcher}">
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Margin="0,2" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
                        Width="250px" />
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=OneWay}" 
                        Width="300px">
                        </TextBox>
                    </WrapPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.Resources>
        </ItemsControl>
    <!--</ScrollViewer>-->
```

Any pointers?

Bonus point: Where should I add a ScrollViewer in order to have the behavior shown in my mockup?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WrapPanel` has, as well as the `StackPanel`, an `Orientation` property, which defaults to `Vertical`. So your list should wrap (assuming you have enough space at hand) if your `ItemsPanelTemplate` looks like this:

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

About the ScrollViewer:

The desired behavior should be achieved by defining it like follows (not tested though, and I omitted all for this example unnecessary stuff):

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ItemsControl MinWidth="550" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ScrollViewer}}}" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Thanks! The scrollviewer almost works (the scrollbar remains even when all content is displayed, but I expect it is a matter of tweaking the values)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the `WrapPanel` in the `ItemsPanel` and the `StackPanel` in the `ItemTemplate`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the issue!

Answer (score 1):

why not use the WrapPanel as ItemsPanelTemplate?

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
 </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

as long as the items have space to the left they would be arranged horizontal.